# javascript modify a value of a key of an object inside an array when pushing

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to conditionally push an object inside an array... 
and when condition is not met. I'd like to change a value of a specific key to the object that I am about to push.  It goes like this...

```
var temp = [];
status.forEach(status => {
    event.forEach(event => {
        if (status.id == event.status_id) {
            temp.push({status_id : event.status_id, data : event})
        } else if (event.action_id == null) {
            temp.push({status_id : null, data : event}) 
            //Now, what I want is to change the `status_id` of the `event` that I am about to push into the data array into NULL.
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: So... what's the problem?

Comment: Just set `event.status_id = null`, before/after pushing it to `temp`. Notice, that `event` inside `forEach` is only a reference to the objects in `event` array, hence the value will change in that array too.

Comment: @Teemu thanks man. exactly what I'm looking for